# create multiple objects in a for loop

Tags: python, keras, lstm

I want to create multiple objects in a for loop. My code is like this:

```
regressor1 = Sequential()

# Adding the first LSTM layer and some Dropout regularisation
regressor1.add(LSTM(units = 50, return_sequences = True, input_shape = (X_train.shape[1], 6)))
regressor1.add(Dropout(0.2))

regressor2 = Sequential()

# Adding the first LSTM layer and some Dropout regularisation
regressor2.add(LSTM(units = 50, return_sequences = True, input_shape = (X_train.shape[1], 6)))
regressor2.add(Dropout(0.2))

.
.
.

regressor20 = Sequential()

# Adding the first LSTM layer and some Dropout regularisation
regressor20.add(LSTM(units = 50, return_sequences = True, input_shape = (X_train.shape[1], 6)))
regressor20.add(Dropout(0.2))
```

How do i do this in a for loop?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing special about models, they are objects so you can create a list of Model objects (regressors) in a loop:

```
regressors = list()
for _ in range(20):
  model = Sequential()
  model.add(LSTM(units=50, ...))
  model.add(Dropout(0.2))
  regressors.append(model)
# Now access like you would any array
# regressors[0] etc will give you models.
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a list of objects.
For example:

```
regressor_list = []
for x in range(0,20):
    regressor = Sequential()
    regressor_list.append(regressor)
```

So now for e.x. you can access the 5th regressor object like regressor_list[5].
Hope this helped you :)

Answer (score 2):

bad looking one liner is as follows

```
layer_str = "Sequential().add(LSTM(units = 50, return_sequences = True, input_shape = (X_train.shape[1], 6))).add(Dropout(0.2))"

models_lst = [eval(layer_str) for i in range(1,21)]
```

Note: I would suggest to go with other answer's . but, i am just showing that this can be done in this way too.

Answer (score 0):

You have to first create the objects, add to a list

Then iterate over them to add the detail..

```
lst = [x.Sequential() for x in range(20)]

for i in lst:
    i.add(LSTM(units = 50, return_sequences = True, input_shape = (X_train.shape[1], 6)))
    i.add(Dropout(0.2))
```